# A question about quantifiers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, first-order-logic

I'm trying to prove this theorem:

> Let $F$ and $G$ be functions. Then $F=G$ if and only if $\operatorname{Dom}(F)=\operatorname{Dom}(G)$ and $\forall X (X\in \operatorname{Dom}(F)\rightarrow F(X)=G(X))$.

To prove it I need to justify as much as possible my steps by using rules of logic. So this is what I have for $\Longrightarrow$ (I'm working on the second part but it's pretty much the same). My question is specifically on step number 5. If you have any comment or anything I'll be very grateful:

$1)F=G\Longrightarrow \forall X(X\in F \longleftrightarrow X\in G)$ (Definition of $``="$)

$2)\Longrightarrow \forall X(\exists A \exists B (X=(A,B)\wedge X\in F) \longleftrightarrow X\in G)$ (F is a binary relation)

$3)\Longrightarrow \forall (A,B)(\exists A \exists B ((A,B)\in F \longleftrightarrow (A,B)\in G) $ (Properties of $``="$)

$4)\Longrightarrow \forall (A,B)((A,B)\in F \longleftrightarrow (A,B)\in G)$ (Existential elimination)

$5)\Longrightarrow \forall A\forall B (A\in \operatorname{Dom}(F)\wedge F(A)\in \operatorname{Ran}(F) \longleftrightarrow A\in \operatorname{Dom}(G)\wedge F(A)\in \operatorname{Ran}(G) \wedge F(A)=G(A))$ (???It sounds to me like I can introduce quantifiers but I'm not sure and I don't know how to justify it).

$6)\Longrightarrow \forall A\forall B (A\in \operatorname{Dom}(F)\longleftrightarrow A\in \operatorname{Dom}(G))\wedge \forall A\forall B (A\in \operatorname{Dom}(F) \longrightarrow F(A)=G(A))$

($\wedge$ and $\exists$ property. Also simplification of $\wedge$ and $\longleftrightarrow$ )

$7)\Longrightarrow \operatorname{Dom}(F)=\operatorname{Dom}(G) \wedge\forall A (A\in \operatorname{Dom}(F) \longrightarrow F(A)=G(A))$ 
($\forall$ elimination and definition of $``="$).

Comment: $2 \to 3$ is not valid; actually, $3$ is not a proper sentence. Keep in mind that $(A,B)$ is _not_ a variable. Therefore, one _cannot_ quantify over it. // Do you need to produce a reasoning in a natural deduction proof system? If so, you're being too informal, leading to errors; if not, you're likely confusing yourself by the convoluted language you are using.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Yes my proof is supposed to be in the form of natural duduction. I did it this way as a scketch of a general proof, and I put together several steps. Thanks for the notice of step $3)$ I'm thinking about that.

Comment: I see. While it is profitable to create a sketch proof to imagine the steps needed in one's ND proof, it seems to me that you've done too much of an appeal to intuition in your sketch. Particularly in step $4\to 5$, where you completely disregard $B$ without notice, while you actually know it to be $F(A)$ (and this is used crucially). I advise you to delve in some deeper.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thank you so much. I followed your advise and finally realized that everything is reduced to prove that $\forall X(X\in F\longleftrightarrow X\in G)\Longleftrightarrow \forall A\forall B((A,B)\in F\longleftrightarrow (A,B)\in G)$. This makes the proof esencially the same but more "legal".

Comment: I'm glad you managed to sort it out! If you find the time, you are encouraged to answer your own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For completeness' sake, a complete derivation of the theorem in (a form of) natural deduction. We follow the approach set out in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412812/a-question-about-quantifiers#comment884102_412812).

---

For convenience and explicitness, we introduce a predicate $\mathsf{Func}(F)$, with intended reading "$F$ is a function". That is:

$$\forall F:\mathsf{Func}(F) \leftrightarrow ((\forall X \in F:\exists a,b:X = \langle a,b\rangle )\land (\forall a,b,b': (\langle a,b\rangle \in F\land \langle a,b'\rangle \in F) \to b=b') )$$

We now split out the theorem into two parts, i.e. we prove:

- $\mathsf{Func}(F)\land \mathsf{Func}(G) \to (F = G \leftrightarrow \forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F \leftrightarrow \langle a,b\rangle \in G)$
- $(\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\leftrightarrow \langle a,b\rangle \in G) \hskip{4em}\leftrightarrow (\mathsf{Dom}(F) = \mathsf{Dom}(G)\land \forall a (a \in \mathsf{Dom}(F) \to F(a) =G(a)))$

---

In the derivations below, the "Pool" indicates the assumptions a certain line depends on.

**Part 1:** $F = G \to (\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F \leftrightarrow \langle a,b\rangle \in G)$

1. $F = G$ (Assumption) (Pool: 1)
2. $\forall X(X \in F \leftrightarrow X \in G)$ (Extensionality) (Pool: 1)
3. $X \in F \leftrightarrow X \in G$ (Universal Instantiation) (Pool: 1)
4. $X = \langle a,b\rangle \to (X \in F \leftrightarrow X \in G)$ (Implication Introduction) (Pool: 1)
5. $\forall a,b: \forall X: X = \langle a,b\rangle \to (X \in F \leftrightarrow X \in G)$ (Universal Generalisation) (Pool: 1)
6. $F = G \to (\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F \leftrightarrow \langle a,b\rangle \in G)$ (Implication Introduction)

where in the last derivation, we have used that the formula 5. is the proper form for the consequent.

**Part 2:** $\mathsf{Func}(F) \to ((\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F \to \langle a,b\rangle \in G)\to F \subseteq G)$

1. $Y \in F$ (Assumption) (Pool: 1)
2. $\mathsf{Func}(F)$ (Assumption) (Pool: 2)
3. $\forall X(X \in F \to \exists a,b: X = \langle a,b\rangle)$ (Conjunction Elimination) (Pool: 2)
4. $Y \in F \to \exists a,b: Y = \langle a,b\rangle$ (Universal Instantiation) (Pool: 2)
5. $\exists a,b: Y = \langle a,b\rangle$ (Modus Ponens on 1. and 4.) (Pool: 1,2)
6. $Y = \langle\alpha,\beta\rangle$ (Existential Instantiation) (Pool: 1,2)
7. $\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F \to\langle a,b\rangle \in G$ (Assumption) (Pool: 7)
8. $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle \in F \to \langle\alpha,\beta\rangle \in G$ (Universal Instantiation) (Pool: 7)
9. $Y \in F \to Y \in G$ (Some reasoning in Propositional Calculus) (Pool: 1,2,7)
10. $Y \in G$ (Modus Ponens on 1. and 9.) (Pool: 1,2,7)
11. $Y \in F \to Y \in G$ (Implication Introduction on 1. and 10.) (Pool: 2,7)
12. $F \subseteq G$ (Universal Generalisation, definition of $\subseteq$) (Pool: 2,7)

Two more Universal Generalisations suffice to establish the desired expression; interchanging $F$ and $G$ and combining these with **Part 1** yields the first of our bullet points.

**Part 3:** $(\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\to \langle a,b\rangle \in G)\to (\mathsf{Dom}(F) \subseteq \mathsf{Dom}(G))$

1. $\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\to \langle a,b\rangle \in G$ (Assumption) (Pool: 1)
2. $\exists b: \langle\alpha,b\rangle \in F$ (Assumption) (Pool: 2)
3. $\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\in F$ (Existential Instantiation) (Pool: 2)
4. $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle \in F\to \langle \alpha,\beta\rangle \in G$ (Universal Instantiation) (Pool: 1)
5. $\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle \in G$ (Modus Ponens on 3. and 4.) (Pool: 1,2)
6. $\exists b: \langle \alpha,b\rangle \in G$ (Existential Generalisation) (Pool: 1,2)
7. $(\exists b: \langle\alpha,b\rangle \in F) \to (\exists b: \langle\alpha,b\rangle \in G)$ (Implication Introduction) (Pool: 1)
8. $\forall a((\exists b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F) \to (\exists b: \langle a,b\rangle \in G)$ (Universal Generalisation) (Pool: 1)
9. $(\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\to \langle a,b\rangle \in G)\to (\mathsf{Dom}(F) \subseteq \mathsf{Dom}(G))$ (Implication Introduction)

where in the last derivation, we have used that $a \in \mathsf{Dom}(f)$ iff $\exists b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F$; interchanging $F$ and $G$ we establish $(\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\leftrightarrow \langle a,b\rangle \in G)\to (\mathsf{Dom}(F) = \mathsf{Dom}(G))$.

**Part 4:** $(\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\to \langle a,b\rangle \in G)\to (\forall a: a \in \mathsf{Dom}(F) \to F(a) \subseteq G(a))$

1. $\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\to \langle a,b\rangle \in G$ (Assumption) (Pool: 1)
2. $\forall b: \langle \alpha,b\rangle \in F\to \langle \alpha,b\rangle \in G$ (Universal Instantiation) (Pool: 1)
3. $(\exists b: \langle \alpha,b\rangle \in F) \to (\forall b: \langle \alpha,b\rangle \in F\to \langle \alpha,b\rangle \in G)$ (Implication Introduction) (Pool: 1)
4. $(\forall a, b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\to \langle a,b\rangle \in G)\to (\forall a: a \in \mathsf{Dom}(F) \to F(a) \subseteq G(a))$ (Implication Introduction)

where we have chosen to interpret $F(a)$ as the set $\{b: \langle a,b\rangle \in F\}$; interchanging $F$ and $G$ and using **Part 3**, we obtain the desired equality.

---

The above four parts constitute a proof of the two bulleted formulae, which together imply the desired theorem.

The above explicit proof (which still wouldn't be accepted by a formal proof checker) should leave the reader deeply appreciative of proofs written in words, as well as serve as a positive witness to the fact that such proofs can actually be written (because many claim that such is possible, but hardly pursue it to any extent, as it is tedious and -- besides being a good natural deduction proof writing exercise -- not very enlightening).

Comment: Very good job. One can be easily be found that you are typing the thesis. Long and in the right order. +